# Power series expansion of an Operator.

Tags: calculus, operator-theory, power-series, operator-algebras, integrable-systems

I've been reading a paper called "Separation of variables for the quantum $Sl(2,R)$ spin chain" in which the author at one point does a power series expansion I do not understand. The problem is this is a crucial point of understanding the whole Bethe ansatz mechanic so I would like to pass this question on to you.
He defines the so called transfer matrix

(2.16) $t(u) = tr \, T(u) = A(u) + D (u)$ where

(2.13) $T(u) = \begin{pmatrix} A(u) && B(u) \\ C(u) && D(u) \end{pmatrix} = L_1(u) \cdot\dotsc\cdot L_N(u) = \prod_{n=1}^N L_n(u)$

$T(u)$ is called the monodromy matrix the $L_n$ Operators are Lax matrices and defined through the spin operators via: (2.12) $L_n = \begin{pmatrix} u \mathrm{I} + i S_3 && i S_- \\ i S_+ && u \mathrm{I} - i S_3 \end{pmatrix} $ with $I$ being the Identity matrix and $S_a = \frac{1}{2} \sigma_a , S_\pm = S_1 \pm i S_2 $ . The $L$ matrices act nontrivially in different spaces $L_1$ acts in $V_0 \otimes V_1 \otimes \mathrm{I}_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathrm{I}_N$ nontrivial only in $V_0$ and $V_1$ and so on, $L$ acts on $V_0 \otimes V_1 \otimes \dots \otimes V_N $ thus $T$ acts nontrivially on $V_0 \otimes V_1 \otimes \dots \otimes V_N $
The matrix $L$ and $T$ itself act on our auxiliary space $V_0$ while their entries act on our physical space $V_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes V_N$

Now to the main question, in the paper he states:
"Substituting (2.13) into (2.16) and taking into account the explicit form of the Lax operator (2.12) one finds that $t(u)$ is a polynomial of degree $N$ in the spectral parameter $u$ with the operator valued coefficients: $t(u) = 2u^N + q_2u^{N-2} + \dots + q_N $"

I don't see how exactly he arrives at that form?
I substitue 2.13 into 2.16 and arrive at:
$t(u) = A(u) + D (u) = tr_0(L_1(u) \dots L_N(u))$ now if I take 2.12 into account I get:
$t(u) = tr_0(L_1(u) \dots L_N(u)) = tr_0(\begin{pmatrix} u \mathrm{I} + i S_3 && i S_- \\ i S_+ && u \mathrm{I} - i S_3 \end{pmatrix}_1 \dots \begin{pmatrix} u \mathrm{I} + i S_3 && i S_- \\ i S_+ && u \mathrm{I} - i S_3 \end{pmatrix}_N)$ using $tr_{a,b}(A \otimes B ) = tr(A) tr(B) $

I arrive at the form: $t(u) = (u \mathrm{I} + i S_3 + u \mathrm{I} - iS_3)^N = (2u\mathrm{I})^N$.

I would like to know now how does he obtain the solution:
$t(u) = 2u^N + q_2u^{N-2} + \dots + q_N $

Is there something I overlooked?

EDIT: I screwed up taking the right trace, question can be deleted.

Comment: Also: should there be an $n$ on the right side of (2.12)?

Comment: Or are each of the matrices $L_n$ identical?

Comment: That's exactly the clarification I needed.  I wasn't sure what you meant about "acting non-trivially".  It seems, then, that $T = L \otimes L \otimes \cdots \otimes L$, right?

Comment: From the presentation of (2.13), it seems that he really mean $t(u) = tr_1(T(u))$, no? Otherwise, we wouldn't have $A(u) + D(u)$; we'd have $tr(A(u)) + tr(D(u))$

Comment: If we just trace out the first space, however, we're left with a degree $2$ polynomial, which is even further from what he has... perhaps you misinterpreted what the $L_n$ are supposed to do?  Something seems fishy here.

Comment: It would seem, then, that in the Auxiliary space, we have something like $L^N$.  Perhaps this is where the polynomial comes from.

Comment: Usually "formal power series" just means "use the Taylor expansion (the 'power series'), and don't worry about convergence (so it's only 'formal')".  I'm not sure how that helps here, though.

Comment: Actually, it does seem to make sense if you look at $L^N$.

Comment: The trace of these matrices seem to fit the pattern

Comment: No, I mean the matrix product $\overbrace{L \cdots L}^N$.  In other words, for each $L_n$ there is an $L$ that acts non-trivially over $V_0$.

Comment: also, is $N$ meant to be even?  Or might the last term be $q_N u$?

Comment: That seems very strange to me.  If it's supposed to be like that, then what's the general pattern?  What is that "..." supposed to mean, for example, when $N = 3$ or $5$?  I could see that the use of "formal power series" is necessary when $N$ is infinite, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ denote the matrix
$$
L = \pmatrix{u \mathrm{I} + i S_3 && i S_- \\ i S_+ && u \mathrm{I} - i S_3}
$$
My best guess is that whatever the author is getting at has something to do with the fact that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(L^N) = 2I\,u^N + q_{2}u^{N-2} + \cdots + q_N
$$
or, if $N$ is odd,
$$
\operatorname{tr}(L^N) = 2I\,u^N + q_{2}u^{N-2} + \cdots + q_Nu
$$
I could come up with a proof that this will generally happen (i.e. there are no terms $u^{N - k}$ for odd $k$) if that's something you're interested in (this is purely a consequence of how matrix multiplication works).  In the mean time, note that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(L^2) = 2u^2 - 2S_3^2 - S_+\,S_- - S_-\,S_+\\
\operatorname{tr}(L^3) = 2u^3 - (6S_3^2 + 3 S_+S_- + 3S_-S_+)u
$$

Comment: I've got the feeling that in your form u assume $L_+$ and $L_-$ are commutating? Problem is $L_+$ and $L_-$ do not commutate, so $S_+S_- + S_-S_+ \neq 2 S_+S_- $

Comment: @Mareck My mistake, put it into Wolfram and didn't take that into account.     That doesn't change much, though.

Comment: Might be my imagination but shouldn't the bracket be $(6S_3^2 + 3S_+S_- + 3S_-S_+)$. Oh and thanks a lot, that really helped me.

Comment: You were right about the sign.  For your last comment, see my latest comment on the question.  I assume that the author *meant* that the exponent of $u$ should decrease by $2$ each time, and that adding a constant term at the end was simply a mistake.